# Notes or books to quickly get started on the basics of signal processing or wireless communication

Tags: reference-request, channelcoding, fading-channel, mimo, multi-channel

I'll soon start working in signal processing, specially wireless communication systems. Hence I'd like to get a quick understanding of MIMO and related systems, for example, the topics like:

1) where and how the model $y=Hx + n$ arise,

2) fading, Rayleigh fading,

3) channel capacity, channel state information,

4) other basics one must know

etc.

Note that, I'm not asking for the mathematically rigirous literature; I'm aware I'll need to work with large dimensional random matrices and I'm familiar with the random matrix side of things (I'm a mathematcian), but I'd like to know something bit more basic and applicartion-oriented, for example, where those random matrices actually arise, how the models are formulated etc.

An intrductory (easy to understand) material that'd help me gain all these necessary basics in a week (or say ten hours) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Fat32 gave some very good answers so I'll just leave this as a comment. You situation sounds like mine when I was offered an internship at a research lab doing work involving wireless and MIMO systems. They gave me the "Fundamentals of Wireless Communication" text by David Tse to read. You can even skip right to the chapters about MIMO and just start from there as that is what I did. Hope this helps!

Comment: Here is the link: https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/wireless_book.html

Comment: @Engineer: thank you for the reference, will surely look into it! The whole pdf is also available online it seems- http://ee.sharif.edu/~wireless.comm.net/references/Tse,%20Fundamentals%20of%20Wireless%20Communication.pdf, but it's a big 647 page book! I'll see if I can pick things up directly from the MIMO chapters only.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most readable (imho) authors on the communication systems is Simon Haykin and the following book from him would probably address most of the issues you would encounter in a wireless communication system analysis.

- Modern Wireless Communication Systems

Similar known authors do have related books, but I guess most compact academic begining would be this one.

It's not a practical book by any comparison, and therefore does not discuss any bit of a practical application of any of the mathematical analysis it intruduces...

If this book contains advanced materials then you may consider reading its pre-requisites from the same author:

- Introduction to Analog and Digital Communications

Furthermore you can enhance your Matlab applications on the fundamental communication systems by the following book from the author Proakis.

- Contemporary Communication Systems using Matlab

Comment: Much appreciated your answers, I'll surely take a look at all three! But because of the time constraint, I'll need a faster pace introduction from the beginning covering just the necessary materials, say within a week, or say in three to four lectures, or ten hours of reading. Are these books that faster paced, or are there chapters in these books that're more relevant to my question? Thanks again!

Comment: what you are looking for is a face to face training on wireless communication systems... No single book can replace that. The closest would be some power-point slides or lecture summary notes; but they will be hard to understant alone by self study.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you a book from Emil Björnson. He is a professor on the Linköping University and also produces a lot of content on his Youtube channel  (which I will not link to avoid getting flagged as spam). His book is completely free and gives a very detailed overview:

> Emil Björnson, Jakob Hoydis and Luca Sanguinetti (2017), “Massive MIMO
> Networks: Spectral, Energy, and Hardware Efficiency”, Foundations and
> Trends® in Signal Processing: Vol. 11, No. 3-4, pp 154–655.